# Spring security losing parameters

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a login in grails 2.0.0.M2 with spring-security-core plugin 1.2.4. I’m trying to do a callback with some parameters ex. "www.mydomain.com/foo?callbackURL=http://google.com"
then when the login fail, the URL lost the parameters and redirect to "www.mydomain.com/auth?login_error=1".

How can I do to keep parameters on a fail login?.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform request to an unauthorized url, Spring Security saves that [request on your session](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.html), and then when you successfully authenticate, it redirects you to that request.

You can use the following code for getting initial target url:

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)session.getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
String requestUrl = savedRequest.getFullRequestUrl();
```

Here is more information regarding [application flow on authentication success and failure.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-flow-handling)